# How to log where a class was loaded from on OpenJDK 17? (Unrecognized VM option 'TraceClassLoading')

Tags: java, jvm

With OpenJDK 8, the `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` flag logs which jar a class was loaded from:

```
$ java -XX:+TraceClassLoading ...
[Loaded java.lang.Object from jdk1.8.0_202/jre/lib/rt.jar]
```

The flag is not recognized by OpenJDK 17 and newer:

```
$ java -XX:+TraceClassLoading ...
Unrecognized VM option 'TraceClassLoading'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

What is the equivalent flag for OpenJDK 17?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OpenJDK 9 and newer, pass `-Xlog:class+load=info` instead of `-XX:+TraceClassLoading`:

```sh
$ java -Xlog:class+load=info ...
...
[info   ][class,load] java.lang.Object source: jrt:/java.base
```

OpenJDK 9 deprecated `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` and introduced a new ['Unified Logging Framework'](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html#GUID-BE93ABDC-999C-4CB5-A88B-1994AAAC74D5) (the `-Xlog` option) as part of [JEP 158](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/158).

For OpenJDK 9 through 15, the following warning was logged if `-XX:+TraceClassLoading` was passed:

```
-XX:+TraceClassLoading is deprecated. Will use -Xlog:class+load=info instead.
```

Starting in OpenJDK 16 the flag was ignored:

```
Ignoring option TraceClassLoading; support was removed in 16.0
```

Starting in OpenJDK 17, the flag is rejected.